# Merging fails in mercurial with "Operation not supported"

Tags: vim, mercurial

I've set up my ~/.hgrc as per https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingWithVim to use vimdiff.

```
[ui]
merge = vimdiff

[merge-tools]
vimdiff.executable = vim
vimdiff.args = -d $base $local $output $other +close +close
```

However, when I try to run the actual merge, it just fails out not very helpfully with the following:

```
bash-3.2$ hg --debug merge
  searching for copies back to rev 7
resolving manifests
 overwrite None partial False
 ancestor 88aaf3a2e10f local 311bb03b96cd+ remote 29bec6ac5dd3
 junk: versions differ -> m
preserving junk for resolve of junk
updating: junk 1/1 files (100.00%)
picked tool 'vimdiff' for junk (binary False symlink False)
abort: Operation not supported: /Accounts/rainest/mtest/junk.orig
```

Any idea why it's doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.

It turns out there's a very specific bug in Python2.6's shutil library that occurs if you're working with NFS mounts on a BSD-like system. More information, and the fix, can be found at http://bugs.python.org/issue7512.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you installed it Mercurial usually comes with vimdiff pre-configured for merging.  On my machine that's in `/etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/mergetools.rc` but I imagine it's different in your OSX box.

You might want to check to see if it doesn't already use vimdiff for merging if you remove all of that from your `.hgrc`.

You can use the command `hg showconfig --debug` to see all the per-user, per-repo, and system-wide configuration items that are in effect.  If you see vimdiff in there after the lines you've added are removed then you might be good to go.